# First value from second column with the smallest value from column 1

Tags: tcl

I have this file

```
2  1
12 2
34 1
56 1
45 3
33 2
77 1
83 2
62 3
75 3
```

I want to take the first value from second column with the smallest value from column 1
like this

```
2  1
12 2
45 3
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a linear scan and a little bit of use of an associative array, something like this:

```
set f [open $filename]
foreach line [split [read $f] "\n"] {
    # ASSUME: valid Tcl list of numbers
    lassign $line col1 col2
    if {![info exists minima($col2)] || $minima($col2) > $col1} {
        set minima($col2) $col1
    }
}
close $f
foreach col2 [array names minima] {
    puts "$minima($col2) $col1"
}
```

Imposing whatever sorts of parsing, sorting and formatting you require are left to you.